# Automatically run an application when a windows service restarts

Tags: .net, windows, service

We have a windows service used for caching purposes. Is there a way to automatically run an application (say for example a console application) every time a windows service is restarted.

Comment: in which language do you want to write the app?

Comment: did you try just process.start

Answer (score 0):

this checks the status of the service you are looking for, use it in a while loop, when the service status returns running

```
string machineName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceMachineName"];
string serviceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceName"];
ServiceController service = new ServiceController( serviceName, machineName );
return service.Status;
```

start your app with something like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
//process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\WINDOWS\system32\iisreset.exe";
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C iisreset /STOP";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

so that when the app exits the loop goes on seeking the process...